# Can I use TensorFlow distribute training with heterogeneous machines?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing, tensorflow2.x

I have two machines, machine 1 has GPUs and the machine2 only has a CPU.
I want to know if the two machines can use Multi-worker training in TensorFlow, that is, during the distributed training, machine1 uses GPUs and machine2 uses CPU.

The version of Tensorflow is 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.
When I do distribute deep learning followed this tutorial:

> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras

There are some errors happened:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Collective Op CollectiveBcastSend: Broadcast(1) is assigned to device /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with type GPU and group_key 1 but that group has type CPU [Op:CollectiveBcastSend]

After I set machine1 to use CPU by code:

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Training will run successfully using the CPUs of both machines.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Multi-worker to train models with TensorFlow across multiple machines. By default, TensorFlow trains models on your systems CPU, but if you have an Nvidia GPU, you could install CUDA, which would allow you to train models on the GPU.

Comment: I want to use two machines to do distributed learning. The machine1 has GPU's and has installed CUDA/Cudnn, but the machine2 only has CPU. Both machines have installed Tensorflow2.1.0.Can I use machine1' GPUs and machine2's CPU to do distributed learning?

Comment: Personally, I have never trained a model across multiple machines, but from what I have read, it should be possible to train models on different machines, but as long as you are using Multi-worker. If you have CUDA installed on the computer with the GPU, then when you begin training your model on that computer, it should automatically go to your GPU.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will do some experiments for this situation, and when I get some result I will update this question.